# How can i make this text in Blender?

Tags: text-object

Hi all how can i make this text in blender. IS there please any tutorial or Tips 
[image]

Comment: Download a similar font for example: https://www.dafont.com/ai-pointe.font then create a texture image from it in a picture editor or use as text in Blender.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and this web page